# Symfony2 Multiple databases configuration/connections and entity managers

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I want to connect another database to my project and link it to my bundle.
There is my configuration for the database connection :

```
# Doctrine Configuration in app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
            forum:
                driver:   %database_driver2%
                host:     %database_host2%
                port:     %database_port2%
                dbname:   %database_name2%
                user:     %database_user2%
                password: %database_password2%
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager:   default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:       default
                mappings:
                    ProjectBackBundle: ~
                    ProjectFrontBundle: ~
                    ProjectUsersBundle: ~
            forum:
                connection:       forum
                mappings:
                    ProjectForumBundle: ~
```

The second database (forum) already exists and I check the connection informations. 
When I go to the website I have this error : 
*Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical*

There are the command I execute in order to generate de mapping :

```
php app/consolde doctrine:mapping:convert xml src/Project/ForumBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force --em="forum"
```

But this command is infinite, it is not executed. Why ? Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, you are probably using FOSUserBundle, and you have to tell it which entity manager to use, just like your own bundles. Your configuration for your 'default' entity manager should look like this:

```
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                ProjectBackBundle: ~
                ProjectFrontBundle: ~
                ProjectUsersBundle: ~
                FOSUserBundle: ~
```